# How long would it take to sail from New Orleans to Belize in late Summer 1867?

Tags: 19th-century, naval, navigation, steamboat

I’m writing a story where the characters need to travel by sea from New Orleans to Belize. The event takes place in late Summer 1867.  I need to figure out the following:

- What route they would take
- What sort of ship would be most appropriated for the era and waters (schooner, steamboat, etc.)
- How long it would take
- What dangers they might face

The direct route from New Orleans to Belize is approximately 750 nautical miles. A medium-sized steamboat could go about 10 knots in the mid-19th century. But determining the time of travel isn’t as simple a distance / speed. The Gulf Stream runs in the opposite direction, so sailing directly across the Gulf might not be the best choice. Maybe skirting around the coast would be better.

I’ve scoured sailing forums and while some people talk about planning trips like this there’s no real information about the route they might take, expected travel time, etc.

General articles on sailing (e.g. Wikipedia) aren’t helpful. There are modern ferries from New Orleans to Belize, but again that isn’t helpful as these are huge modern day ships, not mid-19th century fishing or cargo boats.

I don’t expect anyone here to have the answers necessarily, but pointing me to resources I may have missed would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: You take the boat going the right direction. Everything else is merely opinion. What time of year (as prevailing winds vary with season)? How much of a hurry are they in (medium sized boats tend to be the fastest, larger are more comfortable, smaller are cheaper and more plentiful etc.)? Do they have the funds to buy a whole boat? I suggest you do some actual research on sailing - let's say knowing the points of sail at a minimum -  and come back with a more sensible question.

Comment: reading Verne's "*Around the World in Eighty Days*" would also give you some essential background for a meaningful question.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I have done research. Where I am coming up short is what route would be most appropriate in July/August. And what sort of ship would be best suited to making the trip (schooner, steamboat, etc.). Simple math says a sailing across the Gulf would take about three days at steady 10 knots assuming no currents. But with the Gulf Stream a direct route may not be the most efficient. Maybe it’s better to sail around the coast?

Comment: If you are looking to see what might have been in common use at the time, there is information in the [congressional record](https://books.google.com/books?id=y1ZHAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306&dq=shipping+new+orleans+to+belize+in+1867&source=bl&ots=8Zfyeg-7XQ&sig=ACfU3U1GNE--1QDbZ974cBC9fFfYWux2mw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik5qCEpr7oAhXL854KHd1qB4sQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=shipping%20new%20orleans%20to%20belize%20in%201867&f=false) concerning shipments of whiskey and tobbacco using schooners as the primary means of transport between New Orleans and Belize between 1866 and 1868.

Comment: A steamship is also mentioned running this route, the *Trade Wind* ran [mail service](https://stampauctionnetwork.com/SR/sr833.cfm) and [passengers](https://books.google.com/books?id=BUxPmuvJeGMC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=shipping+new+orleans+to+belize+in+1867&source=bl&ots=DVa1KFSwmW&sig=ACfU3U0xOIRspKiL1UIa1pLf2EwQ-JhBQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik5qCEpr7oAhXL854KHd1qB4sQ6AEwDXoECA8QAQ#v=onepage&q=shipping%20new%20orleans%20to%20belize%20in%201867&f=false) .

Comment: @justCal This is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You really need to clarify whether your characters are going to be travelling on a commercial ship (in which case there should be schedules around somewhere), or if they're going to be sailing their own boat.  (Or perhaps one they stole :-))

Comment: @jamesqf I haven’t been able to locate schedules in the mid-19th century for voyages between New Orleans and the Yucatán peninsula. They would likely be chattering a private ship.

Comment: Not an answer, but some things to consider. 1) In general, travel other than coastal or inland (river) travel would not have likely used steam, which required availability of refueling. Sail was still the major means of propulsion in that era. Your characters almost certainly sailed. 2) A trading schooner would have been most likely. A full rigged ship would had less reason to be used for such a relatively short hop. 3) Late summer is hurricane season there - are you sure they even made it? (OK, they made it, but had a dramatic interlude. Fiction? No need for a true, documented storm.)

Comment: @UnconditionallyReinstateMonica I researched the hurricane season that year and they’ll be safe so long as they depart before late September. A major hurricane hit the Gulf Coast states in October of 1867. But you’re right, I can always invent a storm!

Answer (score 5):

New Orleans to Cancun is approximately 550 NM, so it would be considered an ocean passage. On a 40 to 50 ft sailboat in good conditions the trip would likely take 4 to 5 days. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/sailing/comments/10dcxs/sailing_across_the_gulf_of_mexicosome_questions/). July is early in the hurricane season, but there were no serious storms reported in that area in late Summer 1867 [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1867_Atlantic_hurricane_season).

Looks like the greatest danger would be seasickness.